# How can I deploy a single metadata element with ForceCode

Tags: vs-code, forcecode

I'm pretty new to the world of Visual Studio Code and the ForceCode plugin. I can't seem to find an easy way to manage multiple environments or deploy from one environment to another without changing my credentials in the force.json settings.

Specifically, I'm trying to manage deployments between a sandbox and other sandboxes and production. Is there an easy way to deploy a single class (or any metadata element for that matter) without completely modifying the entire package.xml file each time?

I'm also interested to know if anyone has a good practice for storing multiple environment credentials to deploy things.

Comment: Honestly, we're not the best place to ask. I would go over to the [repo](https://github.com/celador/ForceCode) and post your questions there; the developer would be best way to get more information.

Comment: It is a question about Salesforce's endorsed external IDE, so the forum seemed reasonable.

Comment: I didn't say it's off topic, nobody's VTC here. I'm just saying that asking the people that *made* it would be a better use of your time than hoping someone here *might* know.

Comment: Makes sense, I will ask there too.